# can php-fpm restart processes based on memory use?

Tags: php-fpm, php7

The max_requests setting is often used to remove processes that may end up using more memory than usual.

Is it possible to configure php-fpm so it will remove the processes that use the most memory first?

Without doing that it may be necessary to wait until the full set of processes gets expired and refreshed, which may never happen if the server is slowing down due to excessive memory use.

The alternative of being conservative with the maximum processes would under-use the server if there is a wide range in memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a such option. Instead of this there is a memory limit option in php-fpm config file: `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M`

Comment: That would apply to the individual PHP process, so it wouldn't work if the extra memory is actually needed for the application